# Error when trying to install a feature in Karaf

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf, opendaylight

I have installed and run Karaf, and I have also installed many features. But when I try this :

```
feature:install odl-openflowplugin-app-lldp-speaker-li
```

I get the following error :

> Error executing command: Can't install feature odl-openflowplugin-app-lldp-speaker-li/0.0.0:
>   null

The same is happening with this :

```
feature:install odl-openflowplugin-li
```

and has happened previously with some other features too. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenDaylight maintains its own repositories outside of Maven Central, which means maven (and therefore pax-url used by Karaf feature service) cannot resolve OpenDaylight artifacts by default.

Try to add the opendaylight maven repo in your ~/.m2/settings.xml file: see the opendaylight [official docs](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/GettingStarted:Development_Environment_Setup#Edit_your_.7E.2F.m2.2Fsettings.xml).

After this, you should also double check to install the right feature repo in Karaf with the `feature:repo-add` command, for example:

```
karaf@root()> feature:repo-add \
    mvn:org.opendaylight.controller/features-mdsal/1.3.4-Beryllium-SR4/xml/features
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Possibly it is enough or required in addition to add the OpenDaylight repository to the repository list attribute `org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories` in `$KARAF_HOME/etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg`.